# Apply vector exponents to columns of matrix

Tags: r

In the [`cmprsk`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cmprsk/cmprsk.pdf) package one of the tests to call `crr` shows the following:

`crr(ftime,fstatus,cov,cbind(cov[,1],cov[,1]),function(Uft) cbind(Uft,Uft^2))`

It's the final inline function `function(Uft) cbind(Uft,Uft^2)` which I am interested in generalizing. This example call to `crr` above has `cov1` as `cov` and `cov2` as `cbind(cov[,1],cov[,1])`, essentially hardcoding the number of covariates. Hence the hardcoding of the function `function(Uft) cbind(Uft,Uft^2)` is sufficient.

I am working on some benchmarking code where I would like the number of covariates to be variable. So I generate a matrix `cov2` which is has `nobs` rows and `ncovs` columns (rather than `ncovs` being pre-defined as 2 above).

My question is - how do I modify the inline function `function(Uft) cbind(Uft,Uft^2)` to take in a single column vector of length `nobs` and return a matrix of size `nobs x ncovs` where each column is simply the input vector raised to the column index?

Minimal reproducible example below. My call to `z2 <- crr(...)` is incorrect:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(cmprsk)

for(seed in c(1, 2)) {
    for(Nobs in c(10, 20)) {
        for(Ncovs in c(2, 3)) {
            set.seed(seed);
            ftime <- rexp(Nobs);
            fstatus <- sample(0:Ncovs,Nobs,replace=TRUE);
            cov1 <- matrix(runif(Nobs*Ncovs),nrow=Nobs);
            cov2 <- matrix(runif(Nobs*Ncovs),nrow=Nobs);
            df <- data.frame(ftime=ftime, fstatus=fstatus, cov1=cov1);

            z1 <- crr(ftime, fstatus, cov1, );
            z2 <- crr(ftime, fstatus, cov1, cov2, function(Uft) Uft^cbind(1:Ncovs));
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply` :

```
Uft <- 1:5
Ncovs <- 6
sapply(1:Ncovs, function(i) Uft^i)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    1    1     1
#> [2,]    2    4    8   16   32    64
#> [3,]    3    9   27   81  243   729
#> [4,]    4   16   64  256 1024  4096
#> [5,]    5   25  125  625 3125 15625
```

In your code :

```
function(Uft) sapply(1:Ncovs, function(i) Uft^i)
```

A better alternative using `outer` :

```
function(Uft) outer(Uft, 1:Ncovs, "^")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vec <- 1:4
ncovs <- 5
matrix(unlist(Reduce("*", rep(list(vec), ncovs), accumulate= TRUE)), ncol = ncovs)
```

gives:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    4    8   16   32
[3,]    3    9   27   81  243
[4,]    4   16   64  256 1024
```